# query by specific value to query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hi i am trying to do a stored procedure in postgresql,
and I have to fill a table (vol_raleos), from 3 others, these are the tables:

```
super
zona | sitio | manejo
1    | 1     | 1
2    | 2     | 2

datos_vol_raleos
zona | sitio | manejo |vol_prodn
1    | 1     | 10     | 0
2    | 2     | 15     | 0

datos_manejos
manejoVR | manejoSuper
10       | 1
15       | 2
```

table to fill

```
vol_raleos
zona | sitio | manejo |vol_prodn
1    | 1     | 1      | 0
2    | 2     | 2      | 0
```

So, what I do is take the data that is in `datos_vol_raleos`, verify that it is in `super`, but first I must convert the `manejoVR` value according to the table `datos_manejos`

```
INSERT INTO vol_raleos
(zona, sitio, manejo, edad, densidad, vol_prod1, vol_prod2, ..., vol_prod36)

select zona, sitio, manejo, edad, densidad, vol_prod1, vol_prod2, ..., vol_prod36
from (

    select volr.*, sup.zona, sup.sitio, sup.manejo, dm.manejo,
    from datos_vol_raleos volr
    left join super sup on (sup.zona = volr.zona and sup.sitio = volr.sitio and sup.manejo = volr.manejo) selrs
    order by zona, sitio, manejo, edad, densidad

) sel_min_max;
```

so here I don't know how to get the `manejoSuper` value from datos_manejos, to later compare

Comment: Where and how do you use the value for manejoSuper in your output?

Comment: I just need to fill the table vol_raleos with that value

Answer (score 0):

You can insert from a select with a couple of joins. For example:

```
insert into vol_raleos 
select s.zona, s.sitio, s.manejo, m.manejoSuper
from super s
join datos_vol_raleos d on (d.zona, d.sitio) = (s.zona, s.sitio)
join datos_manejos m on m.manejoVR = d.manejo
```